# Como hacer para obtener un numero random sin que se repita js

Tags: javascript, array, random, math

Estoy haciendo un juego de preguntas y necesito mostrar de forma aleatoria las preguntas. Este código, funciona a medias. A veces me da el mismo número todo el tiempo, y a veces no, ¿qué puedo hacer para que nunca se repitan los números?

```
let datoUsuario
let contadorAcertadas = 0
let contadorDesacertadas = 0
let preguntasTotales = 0
let arrPreguntasUCM = []
let arrPreguntasXMEN = []
let arrPreguntasTodo = []
let nroRandom;

function contadorDePuntos() {
    preguntasTotales++
    if (datoUsuario != 1 && datoUsuario != 0) {
        contadorDesacertadas++
    } else if (datoUsuario == 0) {
        console.log("break");
    } else {
        contadorAcertadas++
    }
}

function alertScore() {
    if (contadorAcertadas < preguntasTotales * 10 / 100) {
        alert(`Has acertado ${contadorAcertadas}, y desacertado ${contadorDesacertadas}.\nCreo que vos no sabes lo que es Marvel.`)
    } else if (contadorAcertadas < preguntasTotales * 30 / 100) {
        alert(`Has acertado ${contadorAcertadas}, y desacertado ${contadorDesacertadas}.\nBueno, nadie es perfecto...`)
    } else if (contadorAcertadas == preguntasTotales * 50 / 100) {
        alert(`Has acertado ${contadorAcertadas}, y desacertado ${contadorDesacertadas}.\nBien! Seguro que podes hacerlo mejor`)
    } else if (contadorAcertadas == preguntasTotales * 100 / 100) {
        alert(`Has acertado ${contadorAcertadas}, y desacertado ${contadorDesacertadas}.\nSos un expert@!`)
    }
}

function jugarDeNuevo() {
    alertScore()
    contadorAcertadas = 0
    contadorDesacertadas = 0
    preguntasTotales = 0
    elijeJuego = parseInt(prompt("Queres jugar de nuevo? \n 1. Sí \n 2. No "))
    switch (elijeJuego) {
        case 1:
            elijeJuego = parseInt(prompt("Sobre qué tematica queres jugar? Ingresá el nro. \n 1. UCM \n 2. X-men \n 3. TODO"))
            elegirJuego()
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
    }
}

function showQuestion(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        nroRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length))
        datoUsuario = parseInt(prompt(`${arr[nroRandom].pregunta} \n ${arr[nroRandom].opciones}`))
        contadorDePuntos()
    }
    jugarDeNuevo();
}
arrPreguntasUCM = [{
        pregunta: "¿Que raza es aliada de Loki en Avengers? Ingresá el numero correspondiente.",
        opciones: [" 1. Chitauri", " 2. Klyntar", " 3. Kronans", " 0. Para salir "]
    },
    {
        pregunta: "¿Por quien consigue Clint la gema del Alma? Ingresá el numero correspondiente.",
        opciones: [" 1. Viuda Negra", " 2. Bruja Escarlata", " 3. Gamora", " 4. Carol Danvers", " 0. Para salir "],
    },
    {
        pregunta: "¿Que Avenger crea a Vision? Ingresá el numero correspondiente.",
        opciones: [" 1. Iron Man", " 2. Thor", " 3. Bruja Escarlata", " 4. Clint", " 0. Para salir "],
    }

]

function preguntasUCMF() {
    showQuestion(arrPreguntasUCM)
}
// Inicia el juego 
let elijeJuego = parseInt(prompt("Sobre qué tematica queres jugar? Ingresá el nro. \n 1. UCM \n 2. X-men \n 3. TODO"))

function elegirJuego() {
    switch (elijeJuego) {
        case 1:
            preguntasUCMF()
            break;
        case 2:
            preguntasXMENF()
            break;
        case 3:
            preguntasTodoF()
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
// Si no se ejecuta, no inicia el juego
elegirJuego()
```

Comment: En vez de poner spam, puedes mostrar esos casos que funcionan (con qué valores) y los casos que no. Te sale algo en la consola del navegador? También va en la pregunta. La puedes [edit]. La puedes [edit]. La puedes [edit]. La puedes [edit]. La puedes [edit].La puedes [edit].La puedes [edit].La puedes [edit].La puedes [edit].La puedes [edit].La puedes [edit].

Comment: Para elegir de forma aleatoria un valor de una lista, se baraja la lista y se toma un elemento. Si no quieres volver a sacar dicho elemento, simplemente actualizas la lista sin ese valor y cuando necesitas otro, vuelves a barajar y sacas uno, así sucesivamente hasta que la lista queda vacía. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

saludos, tienes en tu funcion "showQuestion" la variable nroRandom a la cual podrías hacerle una pequeña mejora, primero veamos que esta pasando.

Estas utilizando la funcion Math.random() esta funcion te devuelve un numero entre 0 y 1 perfecto! acto seguido multiplicas el valor devuelto por la funcion por arr.length, esto esta bien pero recuerda que los arrays empiezan a contar desde 0 lo que quiere decir que arr.length tiene un valor de 2 ya que tu array tiene 3 elementos, al usar Math.floor() devuelve el máximo entero menor o igual a un numero, lo que quiere decir que la única forma de que devuelva 2 (para mostrar la ultima pregunta) es que el Math.random() devuelva exactamente 1 (dificil) entonces su valor devuelto será en mayoria 0 o 1.

Algo que te puede ayudar: Cambia el Math.floor() por un Math.round() te funcionara mejor para este caso. :) que tengas lindo día, cualquier cosa estoy atento

Comment: Hola! Gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo te invito a leer [answer]. Añadir código de ejemplo en un [mcve] sería un plus muy positivo a tu respuesta. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Saludos